# Vectors as feature for training in caret, R

Tags: r, r-caret

I'm learning machine learning through using the R package caret, which have a lot of nice tools, however I wonder if I have a vector(or matrix) of numerical values as a feature for each predictor row.

**Is there a neat way of getting this in the dataframe?**

**Or will I have to explicitly make columns for each index?**

If not, does caret(or similar) packages support list data or lists of lists as input? eg.

```
x <- list(c("a","b","c"), c(TRUE, FALSE, TRUE), list(c(1,2,3), c(3,4,5),c(5,6,7))
```

*Answer to suggestion from comments:*
Suggestion returns:

```
   V1  V2    V3 V4 V5
1  a  TRUE   1  3  5
2  b  FALSE  2  4  6
3  c  TRUE   3  5  7
```

I'd like something like:

```
   V1 V2     V3 
1  a  TRUE   (1, 2, 3)
2  b  FALSE  (3, 4, 5)
3  c  TRUE   (5, 6, 7)
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to do here. Factors can easily be put into a data.frame. Why would `x <- data.frame(V1=factor(c("a","b","c")), V2=c(TRUE, FALSE, TRUE), V3=c(1,2,3), V4=c(3,4,5), V5=c(5,6,7)))` be unacceptable?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I've tried to explain in the question (for better formatting)

Comment: Please explain downvote, so I can improve the question :)

Comment: I didn't downvote you, but maybe explaining why you need your data formatted like this or what the data means would be helpful. Is column V3 a predictor or your outcome? If it's the outcome, does it mean that row is classified as either 1 or 2 or 3 or what?

Comment: Anyway, the short answer is that you will almost certainly need to convert to a `data.frame` or `matrix` or something similar. See `?caret::train` for details. If you want help getting to that format, you might want to provide additional information in your question.

Comment: Thank you for your help @DunderCheif I appreciate it :)   The reason for putting a vector(or matrix) in the dataframe/matrix as a "feature" <- predictor of the outcome is that when doing calculation on data you might not be able to reduce output data get a single number but instead maybe a **long** vector of numbers eg. corresponding to some arbitrary curve.

Comment: Then have a separate column for each point of the curve.

Comment: OK, if this is "the only" or smartest way to do this with the caret package, this answers my question. Thank you! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as the vectors are of equal length, you may have each element of your vector as a separate column.

```
data.frame(V1=c("a","b","c"), 
           V2=c(TRUE, FALSE, TRUE), 
           V3=c(1,3,5), 
           V4=c(2,4,6), 
           V5=c(3,5,7)))
```